# Manipulating svg through viewBox

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I have started working on `svg` and I am stuck. I want to put dropdown icon at the end of the a particular `li`.

The code for this is given below:

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
<mask id="dropdown-mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="4" y="5" width="8" height="6">
</mask>
<g mask="url(#dropdown-mask)">
    <rect width="16" height="16" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.54"/>
</g>
```

Comment: your question is not very clear. Besides the mask you are using lacks the shape you intent to use as a mask. Please try `<mask id="dropdown-mask" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
  <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="7" fill="white"/>
</mask>`

Comment: @enxaneta I tried its not working..I want it end of a particuler li element

Comment: Your code is incomplete. First, add the missing part of the `<svg>` code. Second, provide a use case (your code with `<li>`) to help us understand where is the problem.